# I can't reduce the size of the form with resize

Tags: c#, forms

I am creating a form in windows forms and I need the user to be able to resize it according to the size of the monitor. So far so good. I set FormBorderStyle = Sizable, and with that I was able to increase the size of the form, but I cannot decrease the size. I need to decrease the size.
Can someone help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you ensured the form's [`MinimumSize`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.minimumsize?view=net-5.0#System_Windows_Forms_Form_MinimumSize) is correctly set?

Comment: This should be a comment

Comment: Yes, my MaximumSize is Width: 700; Height: 980 and my MinimumSize is Width: 700; Height: 400.

Comment: My width is the same because I don't want this dimension to be changed, but the height. But I can't resize the form to be 400 tall.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [SystemInformation.WorkingArea](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.systeminformation.workingarea) :

```
Location = SystemInformation.WorkingArea.Location;
Size = SystemInformation.WorkingArea.Size;
```

Or the [Screen](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.screen) :

```
  Location = Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Location;
  Size = Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Size;
```

Also you can get information from required [monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.screen.allscreens).

The working area if the desktop available space without any task and tool bars.

Keep in mind that the ability to change the size of the form if conditioned by the `MinimumSize` and `MaximumSize` properties of the form, and any value outside the limits is set to the corresponding limit.

There is also the `WindowsState` property having the `WindowsState.Maximize` enum value.

Comment: I got it. Thanks.

Comment: Do you know how to activate the scroll bar as the content of the form is hidden?

Comment: Can you clarify this question, please? I do not understand.